# How does "import pythoncom" find the right files?

Tags: python, windows, python-import, pywin32, pth

NB: I know the proper solution is just to do `pip install pywin32` and let everything be done automatically, but here this question is about the internals of `pythoncom`.

When doing `import pythoncom`, it works, but:

- in "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", there is `import pywintypes`, but **no pywintypes.py** or .pyd or .dll is present in the `site-packages` directory. How can it "magically" find `pywintypes`?
- when doing `print(pythoncom.__file__)`, we see:

  ```
  'C:\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32\\pythoncom38.dll'
  ```

  How is this stunning behaviour possible internally? (i.e. pythoncom.py that we imported is now recognized as another file, a .dll)
- Also, `pythoncom.py` contains:

  ```
  # Magic utility that "redirects" to pythoncomxx.dll
  import pywintypes

  pywintypes.__import_pywin32_system_module__("pythoncom", globals())
  ```

**What and where is this (I quote) "magic utility" that redirects to `pythoncomxx.dll`?**

I don't see where this utility is called when doing just `import pythoncom`.

Comment: Check out `pywin32.pth` in your site-packages folder. These pth's are processed at interpreter start, allowing them to add more module search folders. In this case, amongst others `win32/lib` is added, which is where `pywintypes.py` lives.

Comment: I think you can post this as an answer @Jeronimo, I'll accept it.

Comment: See [`site`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/site.html#module-site) for the documentation for this magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the magic utility is [`pywintypes.__import_pywin32_system_module__`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/Lib/pywintypes.py) combined with [`_win32sysloader`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/Lib/pywintypes.py).

The DLL path is [built here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/3e9da59af065a35485107a688e588690ffd72cdf/win32/Lib/pywintypes.py#L27) (where modname is 'pythoncom'):

```
    suffix = "_d" if "_d.pyd" in importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES else ""
    filename = "%s%d%d%s.dll" % (
        modname,
        sys.version_info[0],
        sys.version_info[1],
        suffix,
    )
```

which gets passed to [_win32sysloader](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/3e9da59af065a35485107a688e588690ffd72cdf/win32/Lib/pywintypes.py#L66):

```
    found = _win32sysloader.LoadModule(filename)
```

which is a C++ file that [loads the DLL](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/3e9da59af065a35485107a688e588690ffd72cdf/win32/src/_win32sysloader.cpp#L61):

```
    HINSTANCE hinst = LoadLibraryEx(modName, NULL,
                                    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS |
                                    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR);
```

The final result is the path of the loaded DLL, which gets registered as a Python module [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/3e9da59af065a35485107a688e588690ffd72cdf/win32/Lib/pywintypes.py#L111):

```
    # Load the DLL.
    loader = importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader(modname, found)
    spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(name=modname, loader=loader, origin=found)
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
```

As for why pywintypes, it should be under [`Lib/site-packages/win32/lib/pywintypes.py`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/Lib/pywintypes.py). But if you actually import it you get another DLL path:

```
>>> import pywintypes
>>> sys.modules['pywintypes']
<module 'pywintypes' (C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes312.dll)>
```

But that's because `pywintypes` uses its own [`__import_pywin32_system_module__` function to replace itself](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/3e9da59af065a35485107a688e588690ffd72cdf/win32/Lib/pywintypes.py#L124):

```
__import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
```

And finally, the reason that importing `pywintypes` from `Lib\site-packages\win32\lib` works is due to the library's [`pywin32.pth` file](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/pywin32.pth) (per @Jeronimo's comment), a [path configuration file](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/pywin32.pth). This file is automatically imported at interpreter start, and the paths there are added to the import paths.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Note: for the answer to be complete, you might want to include the role of the `.pth` file, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78019567/how-does-import-pythoncom-find-the-right-files/78021250#comment137545511_78019567

Comment: @Basj Good point, I've added a paragraph about that.